# Problem with Experience Manager Component Border Overlay

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, 2013-sp1

The project I am working on has article pages where the article content fills the whole screen from top to bottom, left to right (its pages are shown in an iPad app, rather than a traditional desktop browser). The problem is that this means that the green border around the component presentation does not show (I guess its outside the boundaries of the page), neither do I see the properties button at the top right, so I cannot edit Metadata.

Is there any (supported or unsupported) way to modify the positioning of the Experience Manager overlays to get around this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Depending a bit on your actual HTML, I think the only solution you have is to use a different stylesheet for staging, where you get more room around your borders so everything shows.

Since you mention the pages are normally shows in an ipad app, maybe it is an idea to have a different style sheet for desktop browsers and show an ipad background around the page?

There isn't really any other way to deal with the XPM borders than through CSS (since that is all they are, styling on the `SPAN`/`DIV` tags). You might need to skip the automatically generated `SPAN`/`DIV` tags and generate them yourself around the editable content (including the XPM comments required as indicated [here](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/TridionUI2012FunctionsForUseInHtmlTemplates)), and use CSS on them (like giving them an XPM class). See also my [blogpost](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/having-fun-with-experience-manager) on [Tridion Developer](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/having-fun-with-experience-manager) (the last paragraph), you could go all overboard and generate the Component Presentation border completely separate from your actual content (although it makes sense to place it around the content of course).

Comment: Thats where device preview comes in... It really should be the same on staging and live, and we use device preview to check the ipad-esque layout, but maybe you have a point - if we do a device/browser dependent CSS we might get there...

Comment: @WillPrice agreed, but still you could have a different view for a desktop browser, giving you more room to see your borders (skip the ipad around it and leave that for the device preview, then editing inside the device preview will only be dysfunctional)